# Crystal Reports remove everything after last occurance of specific character

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have been having some problems with a report, not knowing why I was having them until about 30 hours of troubleshooting. I learned that the owner of this report before me has an instr that will wipe out the rest of the string after a hyphen.

My problem is, sometimes there are multiple hyphens. I have been trying to figure out a way to write the following which will allow everything after the last hyphen to be removed.

Again sometimes there is one hyphen in a string, others there are two and potentially there could be three. I want everything AFTER the final hyphen to be cut out.

Here is the original formula;

```
LEFT({@1ST NAME}, INSTR({@1ST NAME},"-")-1)
```

Comment: can you please post a sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

1) get first "-" from a reversed string (effectively the last occurence) 
2) then get length of the string minus the position of the "-" in reverse

```
left({Command.mytext},len({Command.mytext}) - instr(strreverse({Command.mytext}),"-",1))
```